# How do I add files from an EC2 instance's current directory to S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm struggling to write the proper command to copy files from an EC2's current directory to S3. For my tests, I've been running these commands:

```
echo 'first' >> first.csv
echo 'second' >> second.csv
echo 'third' >> third.csv

ls

aws s3 cp . s3://bucketname/sub
```

The script is being run via datapipeline so I can see `ls` being executed. However, when it hits the last line, there's some error output. Specifically, the error output is:

`upload failed: ./ to s3://bucketname/sub/ [Errno 21] Is a directory: u'/mnt/taskRunner/'`

What would be the correct path name or directory to provide in the first argument after `cp`?

Comment: Try using `aws s3 sync` instead. I think your question might be a duplicate of this one: http://serverfault.com/questions/682708/copy-directory-structure-intact-to-aws-s3-bucket

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the `--recursive` flag to your `aws s3 cp` command;

```
aws s3 cp . s3://bucketname/sub --recursive
```

From the manual/info page for the s3 cp command:

> --recursive (boolean) Command is performed  on  all  files  or  objects
>          under the specified directory or prefix.

In general for the AWS CLI you can use `aws <command> help` and `aws <command> <subcommand> help` for command manual/info pages. (In this case: `aws s3 cp help`)